# what is the meaning of the label moving to register and sub?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
given a a label 
L1: db "beat it",10,0
L2:


what is the meaning of:
mov eax,L2
sub eax,L1
```

L2 to register, and sub register from label include string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MOV EAX,L2` moves the address the label represents to the register.

Unlike `MOV EAX,[L2]` which gets a value (the content of the memory) from that address.

Comment: It subtracts the other address, giving to size of what's in between.

Answer (score 2):

**It's a pointlessly inefficient way to do at runtime what you should have done at assemble time with `mov eax, L2 - L1` to get the number of bytes between those labels.**  i.e. get the assembler to calculate the `sizeof` the array for you, instead of hard-coding the constant.

Normally you'd do something like `L1_length equ $ - L1` to define an assemble time constant.  See [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly)

But anyway, since the symbol isn't inside `[]` (and this is NASM, not some other flavour of Intel syntax), `L1` is an immediate operand; the absolute address of the symbol (in this case defined by a label).

For example, `mov eax, L2` puts the absolute address of the label into EAX, with a `mov r32,imm32` instruction.